# Can't change value in Input field in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have set a value in useState but whenever I change my value in input field I am not able to change every character which I enters. It's like when I input any character after **Beckham** in the field it gets deleted. Nor I can't delete beckham.

But if I use this like `const [name, setName] = useState("Beckham");` I am able to change value in field.

Is it happening because I have set a value in useState ??

```
const [disable, setDisable] = useState(true);
const [name, setName] = useState("Beckham");

return(
<Text style={{ marginLeft: 10, color: 'darkgrey' }}>Full Name :</Text>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <View style={{ width: (Dimensions.get('window').width) - 50 }}>
                        <Input placeholder='Name' value={name} disabled={disable} onChangeText={ () => setName(name)}/>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons style={{ marginTop: 10 }} name='grease-pencil' size={24} color='black' onPress={() => setDisable(!disable)} />
                    </View>
                </View>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send the new text in the function call so you can change the name state

```
    `onChangeText={(text)=> setName(text)}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the param name in the

> onChangeText

```
 onChangeText = {(name) => setName(name)}
```

And also use TextInput instead of Input

```
<TextInput
   placeholder="Name"
   value={name}
   disabled={disable}
   onChangeText={(name) => setName(name)}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

**We have to set the enteredValue in the state value to update the text in text input.**

Have a try with below code:

```
const [disable, setDisable] = useState(true);
const [name, setName] = useState("Beckham");

return(
    <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10, color: 'darkgrey' }}>Full Name :</Text>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <View style={{ width: (Dimensions.get('window').width) - 50 }}>
                <Input 
                     placeholder='Name' 
                     value={name} 
                     disabled={disable} 
                     onChangeText={(enteredText) => setName(enteredText)}
                />
            </View>
            <View>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons 
                     style={{ marginTop: 10 }} 
                     name='grease-pencil' 
                     size={24} 
                     color='black' 
                     onPress={() => setDisable(!disable)} 
                />
            </View>
        </View>
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setName(name)` it doesn't change anything because `name` is state. You can use this.

```
onChangeText={setName}
```